# Can't type in my password when waking laptop from sleep mode

Tags: login, suspend

When I put my HP 625 laptop into sleep mode and wake it up, I can move my mouse and click things, but can't type my password with my keyboard at the login screen. I can click the submit password button and it will say it is incorrect. I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I tried to eliminate this error by changing Grub settings to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0". Unfortunately, it doesn't work, and after waking up the system, logging in freezes.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve seen this happen with some keyboards that have some non-standard chipset. The solution has generally been to update the Grub config file, as you’ve done, but with different flags. `nouveau.modeset=0` would be for machines that have Nvidia graphics cards and shouldn’t have any effect on the keyboard. Instead, update your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line to look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0 i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

If your system was generally fine before adding `nouveau.modeset=0` then you should be able to remove it.

The four kernel flags I’ve suggested here will do the following:

| Flag | Action |
| --- | --- |
| i8042.reset | Reset the controller during init |
| i8042.nomux | Don't check presence of an active multiplexing controller |
| i8042.nopnp | Don't use ACPIPnP / PnPBIOS to discover KBD/AUX controllers |
| i8042.noloop | Disable the AUX Loopback command while probing for the AUX port |

You can [read more about these flags here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt). Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Matigo. I made changes yesterday. I was able to test once and the solution helped.